# Azure Pipelines - Apple App Store release notes

Tags: app-store, azure-pipelines

I have a problem publishing an application to App Store using the Apple App Store extension for azure/TFS pipelines.
The field "What's new in this version" is mandatory, and I cannot find a way to set this information in the Apple App Store extension configurations.

[image]

If I'm not mistaken, when I set the "Track" to "TestFlight", the field "What to test" will be set as the "What's new in this version" field -but, when the Track is "Production", I don't have this "What to test" field, only a "Upload Metadata", which I believe it could be used to define the "What's new in this version" but I don't know how.
Another possibility, would be to use the fastlane parameters, but I could not find anything related to "What's new in this version" in those parameters.

[image]

Comment: Hi there, is there any updates for this issue? Please check whether my answer can help you and feel free to comment~

Answer (score 1):

The Azure DevOps Extension tasks use the fastlane tool and the [fastlane docs](http://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/supply/#changelogs-whats-new) provide the method to set the information of "What's New in This Version".

> You can add changelog files under the changelogs/ directory for each
> locale. The filename should exactly match the version code of the APK
> that it represents. You can also provide default notes that will be
> used if no files match the version code by adding a default.txt file.
> fastlane supply init will populate changelog files from existing data
> on Google Play if no metadata/ directory exists when it is run.
>
> ```
> └── fastlane
>     └── metadata
>         └── android
>             ├── en-US
>             │   └── changelogs
>             │       ├── default.txt
>             │       ├── 100000.txt
>             │       └── 100100.txt
>             └── fr-FR
>                 └── changelogs
>                     ├── default.txt
>                     └── 100100.txt
> ```